# Program failed to start - API-MS-WIN-CORE ???.DLL

Tags: qt, dll, windows-8, hyperlink

I develop a C++ software but it seems that on "some" (not all) machines it cannot run (also under Windows 8).

One of my customer says that he has open it with the dependency walker and that some DLLs are missing... all with the name : API-MS-WIN-CORE ???.DLL

But it seems to me that is a system DLL...

My software is a 64 bits software and use QT (I have built it myself), but I can't reproduce the problem on my machine.

Does someone has an idea to help me ?

For information, you can download it at : www.spectralpixel.com

Thanks for your help

Comment: Dependency Walker hasn't been maintained in a long time.  It is not suitable anymore to look at EXEs on modern operating systems.  These DLLs are *not* missing, you wouldn't be able to run any Windows program anymore.  Lots of possible reasons a program wouldn't run, you haven't done anything yet to narrow it down.

Comment: Thx, but this program has been build with VS2010 under Windows 7, so it should run on Windows 7 without problem. Thanks for your comment, but it does not help me a lot :-(

Comment: It fails silently on my system Win 8/64 after presenting dialog for trial period - clicking ok just does nothing. No errors, no event log. I notice dependencies on MSVCR100 (VS2010 redist) but didn't notice them installed.

Comment: It seems that even if we install the MSVCR100 it still does not work ! So, I'm not sure it is related ( One of my customer has VS2010 on his machine but still failed to start it too :-( ).

Answer (score 0):

Following my comment (sorry for answer, I need to post an image) - after a short delay, I see access violations in the event log. Screenshot attached below - maybe helpful? I have Windows 8 64-bit with VS2012 installed and have also installed VS2010 redist x86/x64.

I agree with Hans Passant that the dependency walker is probably a red herring - I can't see evidence of missing dependencies on my system.

[image: eventlog]

Comment: Thanks,

Sure it crash... does this window allow you to got a dump file (.DMP) ? It should help me to track the problem.

Comment: Something else. Now I try to download the VS2010 c++ runtime but on my machine I got the following message "A newer version of Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable has been detected on the machine.". Is it possible that there is "incompatibility" between the DLL on my development machines and the ones with the customers machine, due to this ?

I download the DDLs from : http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/2/2/3224B87F-CFA0-4E70-BDA3-3DE650EFEBA5/vcredist_x64.exe

But cannot find a more recent one !!!

Comment: @Spectral Sorry, I can't catch it for a dump because of your copy protection (software passport?) even with DebugDiag it won't hook the process to get a call stack or a dump file, sorry.